# in a class, what does this code set ? and what is this is_a(arg1,arg2)?

Tags: puppet

Can someone explain this code in details?
I cannot understand this `is_a(arg1, arg2)` and these two affectations

```
$_directory = is_a($directory, Undef) ? {  
true    => $_anothe_var,  
default => $directory,  
}
```

Comment: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_conditional.html#selectors

Comment: thanks Matt ! :)
remains these 2 args ..

Comment: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_data_undef.html As for `$directory`, that is a variable and therefore we need context to explain that. It probably is an input/class parameter for a directory.

Comment: Oh also this: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#is_a. It is worth noting that this code seems to be doing something very sub-optimal, but again we would need context.